# Error 404, when trying to show something in tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, intellij-idea, servlets

I did everything in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_V16I5TPlSE):
But when I'm typing:`http://localhost:8080/spring-sample-1.0-SNAPSHOT/hello`

**This error shows up:**

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report

Message The requested resource [/spring-sample-1.0-SNAPSHOT/hello] is not available

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
```

The only thing I changed was in: **tomcat/bin/setclasspath.bat**, I added one line there:

```
set JRE_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_271
```

Because without that the server does not start

Okey, so my application is really simple, i created mvn project in java 15, then two classes:

**Config:**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"app"})
@EnableWebMvc
public class Config extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[0];
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[0];
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[0];
    }
}
```

**Hello:**

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class Hello {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String get(){
        return "Bycza zagroda!";
    }
}
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>pl.bykowski</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-sample</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Then I packed everything in war file and add it in tomcat manager here: **WAR file to deploy**

After that I clicked **/spring-sample-1.0-SNAPSHOT** in tomcat module

and then typed hello at the end

Any ideas what is going wrong? :/

Comment: The video you provided is not in English. Also, you should not expect that we watch 19 minutes video to understand what you did as code. So, please provide enough code to help us to understand your code and problem so we can help

Comment: @UsemeAlehosaini Sorry, now i fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue: in Config class you provided incorrect values for servlet mapping and servlet config class.
Please change Config class as follows:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"app"})
@EnableWebMvc
public class Config extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[0];
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {Config.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much bro <3 The video maker did not mention about changing Override methods

Answer (score 0):

First of all I recommend to setup JAVA_HOME or JRE_HOME env variable for OS.
For more details: https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-8895.html
In any case changing tomcat's files is not good idea :)

For solving issue with unreachable url please check:

for installed tomcat:

- as rule, name of war file is context name and part of the url(spring-sample-1.0-SNAPSHOT), but that name can be configured in context.xml (Documentation: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html)
- open manager window as you can see in video (http://localhost:8080/manager/html) and find link of your web application

for embedded tomcat:

- the context path should be like artifactId in pom.xml

Comment: The context name is .war file name in my situation. Also in (http://localhost:8080/manager/html) my application is visible as link: (/spring-sample-1.0-SNAPSHOT). ArtifactId = 'spring-sample' in pom.xml        @saver

Comment: What is the deploy status in tomcat for that war application? 
I think, your application has errors during deploying process.
And additional question: how are you going to run application which is compiled to java 15, but tomcat was run under java 1.8? You will get incompatibility java version exception

Answer (score 0):

@saver
**Log from tomcat when deploying:**

```
21-Dec-2020 16:49:22.227 INFO [http-nio-8000-exec-17] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [C:\Users\Damian\Desktop\JAVA\apache-tomcat-8.5.61\webapps\spring-sample3-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war]
21-Dec-2020 16:49:24.113 INFO [http-nio-8000-exec-17] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
21-Dec-2020 16:49:24.138 INFO [http-nio-8000-exec-17] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [C:\Users\Damian\Desktop\JAVA\apache-tomcat-8.5.61\webapps\spring-sample3-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war] has finished in [1,907] ms
```

So which versions of JRE and JDK, Should I use?

Answer (score 0):

@daniep kajoi you should set path on java 15 for tomcat, or change maven.compiler.source attribute in pom.xml on 1.8 version - one of two options.
And I see in yours log that yours path is 'spring-sample3-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war'

```
21-Dec-2020 16:49:22.227 INFO [http-nio-8000-exec-17] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [C:\Users\Damian\Desktop\JAVA\apache-tomcat-8.5.61\webapps\spring-sample3-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war]
21-Dec-2020 16:49:24.113 INFO [http-nio-8000-exec-17] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
21-Dec-2020 16:49:24.138 INFO [http-nio-8000-exec-17] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [C:\Users\Damian\Desktop\JAVA\apache-tomcat-8.5.61\webapps\spring-sample3-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war] has finished in [1,907] ms
```

try to open url: http://localhost:8080/spring-sample3-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war/hello

Comment: I downloaded Java 8, so everything is Java 8 now. And still the same problem. Yea, I know, I tried to create new project with artifactId: spring-sample3.